# Writing out properties specific to a Derived Class

Tags: c#, derived-class

I need to determine which object my code is working with at a certain point and write out only the properties specific to that class. I cannot figure out how to do it. I was told I can do it, but I cannot figure it out. Can someone please show me how to determine which object I am working with and write the properties specific to that class only?

I've looked at other questions asked, but am not smart enough to make it fit my example.

Below, I've re-created an example of the code I am working with. I can see all the code, but I am allowed to only work in one method (for this example called "MethodIAmWorkingIn"). Only modifications I am allowed to make are in that method.

```
public class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestDetailsAndResultsContainer container = new TestDetailsAndResultsContainer();

    DerivedClass1 derivedClass1 = new DerivedClass1();
    derivedClass1.DerivedClass1Prop1 = "DerivedClass1Prop1";
    derivedClass1.DerivedClass1Prop2 = "DerivedClass1Prop2";

    DerivedClass2 derivedClass2 = new DerivedClass2();
    derivedClass2.DerivedClass2Prop1 = "DerivedClass2Prop1";
    derivedClass2.DerivedClass2Prop2 = "DerivedClass2Prop2";

    container.TestDetails.Add(derivedClass1);
    container.TestDetails.Add(derivedClass2);

    TestResult testResult = new TestResult();
    testResult.TestResultProp1 = "TestResultProp1";
    testResult.TestResultProp2 = "TestResultProp2";

    container.Data.Add(testResult);

    Program p = new Program();
    p.MethodIAmWorkingIn(container);
}

private void MethodIAmWorkingIn(TestDetailsAndResultsContainer container)
{
    // I need to see if the container variable holds a DerivedClass1 or DerivedClass2 object.
    foreach (var result in container.TestDetails)
    {
        var classINeedToDetermine = container.TestDetails.FirstOrDefault(m => m.TestDetailsProp1 == result.TestDetailsProp1);

        if (classINeedToDetermine is DerivedClass1)
        {
            classINeedToDetermine = result as DerivedClass1;
        }
        else if (classINeedToDetermine is DerivedClass2)
        {
            classINeedToDetermine = result as DerivedClass2;
        }

        // Now I need to use the classINeedToDetermine object and write its specific properties.
        // ???????????????????? I am stuck at this point ??????????????????

        // I need to write one or the other below. Can this be done?

        // If it is DerivedClass1, I need to write out those properties only.
        Console.WriteLine(classINeedToDetermine.DerivedClass1Prop1);
        Console.WriteLine(classINeedToDetermine.DerivedClass1Prop2);

        // OR

        // If it is DerivedClass2, I need to write out those properties only.
        Console.WriteLine(classINeedToDetermine.DerivedClass2Prop1);
        Console.WriteLine(classINeedToDetermine.DerivedClass2Prop2);
    }
}
}

public class TestDetailsAndResultsContainer
{
public TestDetailsAndResultsContainer()
{
    this.Data = new List<TestResult>();
    this.TestDetails = new List<TestDetails>();
}

public List<TestDetails> TestDetails { get; set; }

public List<TestResult> Data { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TestDetails
{
public string TestDetailsProp1 { get; set; }
public string TestDetailsProp2 { get; set; }
}

public class TestResult
{
public string TestResultProp1 { get; set; }
public string TestResultProp2 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass1 : TestDetails
{
public string DerivedClass1Prop1 { get; set; }
public string DerivedClass1Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass2 : TestDetails
{
public string DerivedClass2Prop1 { get; set; }
public string DerivedClass2Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed a typo at this part, and changed it in the question        // If it is DerivedClass2, I need to write out those properties only.
        Console.WriteLine(classINeedToDetermine.DerivedClass2Prop1);
        Console.WriteLine(classINeedToDetermine.DerivedClass2Prop2);

Comment: What have you already tried? What have you learned from researching your situation?

Comment: You're going to need to use reflection.

Comment: I really don't think reflection is warranted here, unless there are classes that are unknown at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `as` keyword does not do what you think it does.

Your `classINeedToDetermine` is a variable of type `TestDetails`. You can assign a subclass instance to it, but you still cannot access that subclasses specific properties via that variable.

You just need some scope:

```
if (classINeedToDetermine is DerivedClass1)
{
    var derived1 = (DerivedClass1)result;
    Console.WriteLine(derived1.DerivedClass1Prop1);
    // etc      
}
else if (classINeedToDetermine is DerivedClass2)
{
    var derived2 = (DerivedClass2)result;
    Console.WriteLine(derived2.DerivedClass2Prop1);
    // etc   
}
```

This kind of thing is not fun to maintain though.

Another way of doing it would be to use polymorphism: Your `TestDetails` class could define an abstract method called `PrintProperties`, and all your subclasses could implement it.

Then you just have to call `PrintProperties` on every object, without worrying about which subclass they are.

Comment: thanks, I like the idea of adding a PrintProperties to the TestDetails class. That is probably the way I need to go. One thing I forgot to mention earlier is that I'm going to need this for about 12 different objects, which makes the PrintProperties look very appealing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure on what objects mean what here, but it should be something like this:

```
foreach(var v in result.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if(v.DeclaringType == result.GetType())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(v.GetValue(result));
    }
}
```

Again, I wasn't totally clear on your usage of `classINeedToDetermine` versus `result`, but you can change those as you see so fit. I chose `result` as my example since `classINeedToDetermine` was null by that part of your code.

And by the way, this section of your code is redundant. It should be removed for clarity and efficiency.

```
if (classINeedToDetermine is DerivedClass1)
{
    classINeedToDetermine = result as DerivedClass1;
}
else if (classINeedToDetermine is DerivedClass2)
{
    classINeedToDetermine = result as DerivedClass2;
}
```

**Edit:**

On the other hand, if performance is more important to you than being scalable (read: if you know or have control over all the classes you'll be dealing with), you could use this `is` section to do something less, I hate to use this word for this, "generic."

```
if (classINeedToDetermine is DerivedClass1)
{
    var typed = (DerivedClass1)result;

    Console.WriteLine(typed.DerivedClass1Prop1);
    Console.WriteLine(typed.DerivedClass1Prop2);
}
else if (classINeedToDetermine is DerivedClass2)
{
    var typed = (DerivedClass2)result;

    Console.WriteLine(typed.DerivedClass2Prop1);
    Console.WriteLine(typed.DerivedClass2Prop2);
}
```

Comment: Removed my downvote, since you added the last section. I disagree that reflection is a good solution for this. It's brittle, slow, more complex, and it doesn't appear to be necessary since all classes are available at compile-time.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks. I agree, actually. I originally read the question as being a far more sophisticated matter than it sounds like it is. I assumed we were dealing with unknown classes over which we had no control, but as the question is evolving it's seeming more clear that that might not be the case.

Comment: Thanks. I like @Blorgbeard's suggestion above about adding a PrintProperties to my base class and want to try that. I do though want to try your foreach suggestion above just to see how that works so I can learn more than just a solution to my problem though. As for your question above "What did I learn"...not much until you two gave me some suggestions how to approach it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Wannabe yep, if you have control over all of the classes then that's definitely a good way to go. Reflection is inherently slow. Of course if you're lazy and performance isn't the most important thing, or if you just want to play with reflection a bit, you could always make your base class have a `virtual` method that uses that `foreach`, then it isn't quite so urgent that you override it in your inheriting ones. You'd still want to for the performance, but then at least you wouldn't *have* to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Type.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all Properties for your class.  Then you need to get the `MethodInfo` for the Get method via [GetMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getmethod(v=vs.110).aspx).

Once you have the `MethodInfo` you can call [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx), passing in your Derived Class.  You can write then write the result to the Console.